# Rails authorization from scratch with operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan

So I'm making authorization from scratch based on Ryan Bates' railscast.

I figured the problem i'm facing is in this part of code

```
action == 'create' || action == 'update'
```

What I want to say is that if the action is `create` OR action is `update` (so either of them) AND `obj.has_accepted_acceptance?` it should return false, but it returns true unless I eliminate `|| action == 'update'` part of code. only then it works as intended.

So is the problem with the operators?
Thank you in advance for your time!

```
class Permission < Struct.new(:user)

  def allow?(controller, action, obj = nil)
    if controller == "acceptances"
      if action == 'create' || action == 'update' && obj.has_accepted_acceptance?
        return false
      end
    end
    return true 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try grouping your conditions:

```
if (action == 'create' || action == 'update') && obj.has_accepted_acceptance?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActiveSupport `.in?` to convert the first from two clauses to one:

```
if action.in?(%w[create update]) && obj.has_accepted_acceptance?
```

The same in plain old ruby would be:

```
if %w[create update].includes?(action) && obj.has_accepted_acceptance?
```